# Is it possible to list all the functions of a table?

Tags: lua

I'm new to the Lua Programming Language and I can't find a way to list all the existent functions that were defined in a given table. [I've checked the documentation for the debug table](http://www.gammon.com.au/scripts/doc.php?general=lua_debug) and it's possible to get the details only of functions, not of whole tables.

Is there something like the [dir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) function of the Python Interpreter in Lua? Is it possible to list all the methods/functions of a table?

Comment: "defined in a given table": Tip: A function is a value and therefore can be referenced by any variable, including any number of fields in any number of tables. Obviously, as you are asking, functions referenced by a table of interest might also interesting, too. But, to use a function properly, you need the documentation and/or source code.

Comment: Also, without documentation or source code, there is no way of determining if a function is a method, that is, it should be passed a table context as the first parameter ("self"), typically with the ":" syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate and print? Or am I not understanding the question?

```
for i,v in pairs(table_here) do
    if type(v) == "function" then
        print(i,v,debug.getinfo(v))
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me how to do it! That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Ericson You're absolutely welcome! Glad I could help :)